# Install java, tomcat7 or tomcat6 on RHEL5 centos5

Tags: centos, java, tomcat

I wish to install tomcat7 on centos5 sticking on yum but I have

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
java-1.6.0-sun-compat-1.6.0.03-1jpp.i586 from jpackage-generic-nonfree has depsolving problems
--> Missing Dependency: jdk = 2000:1.6.0_03-fcs is needed by package java-1.6.0-sun-compat-1.6.0.03-1jpp.i586 (jpackage-generic-nonfree)
Error: Missing Dependency: jdk = 2000:1.6.0_03-fcs is needed by package java-1.6.0-sun-compat-1.6.0.03-1jpp.i586 (jpackage-generic-nonfree)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                    package-cleanup --dupes
                    rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I've already tried with:

```
yum install java
yum install tomcat6
yum install tomcat7
```

these all end up with the same dependency resolution problem.

The enabled repos are:

```
[jpackage-generic]
name=JPackage (free), generic
mirrorlist=http://www.jpackage.org/mirrorlist.php?dist=generic&type=free&release=5.0
failovermethod=priority
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://www.jpackage.org/jpackage.asc
enabled=1

[jpackage-rhel]
name=JPackage (free) for Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever
mirrorlist=http://www.jpackage.org/mirrorlist.php?dist=redhat-el-$releasever&type=free&release=5.0
failovermethod=priority
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://www.jpackage.org/jpackage.asc
enabled=1

[jpackage-generic-nonfree]
name=JPackage (non-free), generic
mirrorlist=http://www.jpackage.org/jpackage_generic_nonfree_5.0.txt
failovermethod=priority
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://www.jpackage.org/jpackage.asc
enabled=1

# Updates

[jpackage-generic-updates]
name=JPackage (free), generic
mirrorlist=http://www.jpackage.org/mirrorlist.php?dist=generic&type=free&release=5.0-updates
failovermethod=priority
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://www.jpackage.org/jpackage.asc
enabled=1

[jpackage-rhel-updates]
name=JPackage (free) for Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever
mirrorlist=http://www.jpackage.org/mirrorlist.php?dist=redhat-el-$releasever&type=free&release=5.0-updates
failovermethod=priority
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://www.jpackage.org/jpackage.asc
enabled=1

[jpackage-generic-nonfree-updates]
name=JPackage (non-free), generic
mirrorlist=http://www.jpackage.org/jpackage_generic_nonfree_5.0-updates.txt
failovermethod=priority
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://www.jpackage.org/jpackage.asc
enabled=1

[jpackage-generic-6.0]
name=JPackage (free), generic
baseurl=http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/jpackage/6.0/generic/free/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://jpackage.org/jpackage.asc
enabled=1
```

Comment: Question unanswered in serverfault (http://serverfault.com/questions/577137/install-java-tomcat7-or-tomcat6-on-rhel5-centos5)

Comment: Did you tried `yum install jdk`?

Comment: Please [don't cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu), if you want this question here, delete your post on [sf].

Comment: @terdon As per the Q&A you reference, that's a *debate*, not an S.E. rule ;) Some of us are okay with cross-posting  **as long as it is explicit,** which in this case it is, at least here.  *Meaning a parallel comment should be added to the serverfault question.*

Comment: @goldilocks though I personally don't agree with it completely, closing with extreme prejudice seems to be the norm on all SE sites I frequent. Including this one, which even has a specific close reason just for cross-posting. I always thought that was kind of harsh, but having such a close message is certainly indicative of U&L' stance on this.

Comment: @terdon I only see 5 close options none of which involve cross-posting.

Comment: @terdon I've deleted it from serverfault

Comment: @goldilocks it's under off topic => posted on multiple sites.

Comment: @terdon : Kind of a bizarre subclassing.  Anyway, I'll have to interpret that ambiguously as "cross-posted *without references*" ;]  Sad to be on the losing side of history, it seems...unless...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using non-official repositories *will* cause grief (OK, you found that out already ;-). Check either Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux ([EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL)) or Software Collections ([SC](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/1/html/Software_Collections_Guide)) for what you are looking for.

You can do a `yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=jpackage-* clean metadata` (look it up in the manpage) and try again, if it was a hickup with the repository this might now work.

Comment: yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=jpackage-* clean metadata
;    

    yum update java-1.6.0-openjdk

did the job